# ASP.net renders form tag weirdly

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

My code on my ASPX page:

```
<form runat="server" action="productEditCat.aspx?mid=2&catID=<%=catID%>&action=update">
```

This is rendering as:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="productEditCat.aspx?mid=2&amp;catID=&lt;%=catID%>&amp;action=update" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
```

It seems to be url encoding the query?  Any way to stop this?

The variable is being set in the page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the pages action
    string pageAction = Request.QueryString["action"];
    catID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["catID"].ToString());
```

Edit:  some forms allow it, some dont on my site which is very frustrating

Thanks!

tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct behavior; attributes in HTML tags *should* be HTML-encoded.  (That's what you're seeing, not URL-encoding.)

Comment: But not in a URL of the action.  Putting ?name=value&name=value is valid html for an action parameter.  It shouldn't be doing that there

Comment: It's a pain in the ass and inconsistant because I have other form tags that print out just fine.

Comment: Using `?name=value&name=value` as an action attribute, while it *will* work, goes against the HTML spec.  Character references are permitted within attribute values, so ampersands should always be represented as `&amp;`.  See section 5.3.2 of the HTML 4 spec.

Comment: Thanks, but are there any workarounds, I don't want to end up posting all my values everywhere that would get messy and stop people being able to bookmark pages.

Comment: What does using character references within attributes have to do with bookmarking?

Comment: I've deleted my answer as I'd gone off on a bit of a tangent.  @ngroot is correct in that what you are seeing is just HTML encoded.  If you play around with doing HREF's with your example you'll see that the browser considers a URL with "?param1=1&param2=2" and "?param1=1&amp;param2=2" the same in that it correctly resolves the URL.  You don't need to worry how it looks when you view the code, it works correctly in the browser / bookmarks (or at least it should!)

Answer (score 0):

catID should be a property on the rather than a variable